# Python, setting a variable to None

Tags: python

What is the reason for setting variable `prize` to `None`?

```
def which_prize2(points):

    prize = None
    if points <= 50:
        prize = "a wooden rabbit"
    elif 151 <= points <= 180:
        prize = "a wafer-thin mint"
    elif points >= 181:
        prize = "a penguin"

    if prize:
        return "Congratulations! You have won " + prize + "!"
    else:
        return "Oh dear, no prize this time."
```

Comment: If you didn't set it to None, what would happen if points was, say, 100?

Comment: It is very clear what OP is asking. If OP knows all, he won't be asking in the first place and SO will not exist at all.

Answer (score 4):

A `NameError` exception will be raised if variable `prize` does not exist.
It does not matter if variable prize is set to `None` or `""` (empty string) or `0`, because all these values are falsy in Python.

In this particular example prize is set to `None` because it will exits when checked in if/else.
Even if this if/elif block does not create variable prize, variable prize is created before this block:

```
if points <= 50:
    prize = "a wooden rabbit"
elif 151 <= points <= 180:
    prize = "a wafer-thin mint"
elif points >= 181:
    prize = "a penguin"
```